# NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'xxxxxx' for locale 'en'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, message

I am testing the `MessageSource` in `SpringBoot`.  I am getting the following error.  I am trying the latest version of spring boot (3.0.0-M4) and I am not able to figure what has changed.  The code presented here worked in previous versions.  Please help me here.

**Here is the error:**

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'text1' for locale 'en'..
```

I created a maven project in eclipse using SpringBoot initializer with spring starter web and spring starter validation dependencies.

**Here is my project structure:**

[image: image-1]

**Here is the pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ERP-1</name>
    <description>FBH ERP</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Here are my classes

```
@Configuration
@Service
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
                = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames(
                "classpath:/messages/test.properties"
        );
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}


@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
     private  MessageSource messageSource;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String>  tryme() {
        System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("text1",null,Locale.ENGLISH));
        String body = "welcome";
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(body);
    }
    
    
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return errors;
    }
}




@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the complete stacktrace of the error.

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'userexists' for locale 'en'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:161) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at com.test.valid.controller.TestController.tryme(TestController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:960) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:867) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `MessageSource` Bean as per below example.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
            = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames(
            "classpath:messages/test"
    );
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```